# Prevent “Access to a static member of a type via a derived type” when deriving classes having structs with string constants

Tags: c#, resharper

I'm wrapping the ForgeRock REST API implementation in C#. That implementation is layered. There is a base layer on the ForgeRock level, which gets extended for each of their products (like OpenAM, OpenDJ, etc).

Parts of the API layers are definitions of http parameter names (and often a restriction on values) which I've solved with a hierarchy of `KnownParameter` classes, each having structs defining the parameters in structs each having one `Name` and potentially methods or a nested `Values` struct limiting or converting the values.

The code base usually is limited to one product (and the ancestor layer: ForgeRock).

From that perspective, I want to avoid the “Access to a static member of a type via a derived type” warning generated by ReSharper.

Having classes with the same names does help on the one hand (they are the same thing, just from a different namespace perspective, it compiles and works fine), on the other hand: even after renaming `ForgeRock.KnownParameters` into `ForgeRock.KnownParametersBase` ReSharper isn't happy with it. I think in this confined case, it is OK to have this kind of naming

How can I avoid that warnng while still benefiting from , and still benefit from inheritance?

Example code (also [on-line with more URLs](https://bitbucket.org/jeroenp/besharp.net/src/tip/Managed/.NET/C%23/Applications/Compiler/AccessToAStaticMemberOfATypeViaADerivedType/Program.cs) referencing the correct bits of documentation) in four pieces.

`Main` program exhibiting the ReSharper warning:

```
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using ForgeRock.OpenAM;

namespace AccessToAStaticMemberOfATypeViaADerivedType
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            new NameValueCollection
            {
                {KnownParameters.PrettyPrint.Name, KnownParameters.PrettyPrint.Values.True},
                {KnownParameters.Action.Name, KnownParameters.Action.Values.Logout}
            };
        }
    }
}
```

`ForgeRock` namespace with the base `KnownParameters` class:

```
namespace ForgeRock
{
    public class KnownParameters
    {
        public struct PrettyPrint
        {
            public const string Name = "_prettyPrint";

            public struct Values
            {
                public const string False = "false";
                public const string True = "true";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`ForgeRock.OpenAM` namespace with a descendant of the `KnownParameters` class.

```
namespace ForgeRock.OpenAM
{
    public class KnownParameters : ForgeRock.KnownParameters
    {
        public struct Action
        {
            public const string Name = "_action";

            public struct Values
            {
                public const string Logout = "logout";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`ForgeRock.OpenDJ` namespace with a descendant of the `KnownParameters` class.

```
namespace ForgeRock.OpenDJ
{
    public class KnownParameters : ForgeRock.KnownParameters
    {
        public struct QueryFilter
        {
            public const string Name = "_queryFilter";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't help that your example isn't complete... it would really help if you'd make the example stand alone. Note that your example doesn't show *any* inheritance at all... so what do you mean by "still benefit from inheritance"?

Comment: The example code compiles and shows inheritance: `KnownParameters : ForgeRock.KnownParameters`. I tried to put all the sources in one file (including the various namespaces) to make it easier to follow. Should I split them up?

Comment: Gah - I hadn't spotted that the code scrolled down. It really doesn't help that you have multiple classes with the same name, IMO... *Just* giving them different names would make this much simpler (e.g. `KnownOpenAMParameters`, `KnownOpenDJParameters` etc). Then you can refer to the right class at the right time.

Comment: No problem. I'll split the code up. Having classes with the same names does help on the one hand (they are the same thing, just from a different namespace perspective, it compiles and works fine), on the other hand ReSharper isn't happy with it. I think in this confined case, it is OK to have this kind of naming.

Comment: *I think in this confined case, it is OK to have this kind of naming* So just disable that warning? ReSharper lets you disable warnings for a reason...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think in this confined case, it is OK to have this kind of naming.

Well, personally I disagree. It's generally bad for readability when the same name means different things within a program - it's even worse (IMO) when those two names are related by inheritance. But if you really want to use this approach, there are two options:

- Find a way of specifying `ForgeRock.KnownParameters` when you want to use its members, e.g.

  ```
  new NameValueCollection
  {
      {ForgeRock.KnownParameters.PrettyPrint.Name, 
       ForgeRock.KnownParameters.PrettyPrint.Values.True},
      {KnownParameters.Action.Name,
       KnownParameters.Action.Values.Logout}
  };
  ```

  Or you could use a `using` alias:

  ```
  using BaseKnownParameters = ForgeRock.KnownParameters;
  ...
  new NameValueCollection
  {
      {BaseKnownParameters.PrettyPrint.Name, 
       BaseKnownParameters.PrettyPrint.Values.True},
      {KnownParameters.Action.Name,
       KnownParameters.Action.Values.Logout}
  };
  ```
- Disable the R# warning, if you're happy that you're accessing the member of `ForgeRock.KnownParameters` via `ForgeRock.OpenAM.KnownParameters`, like using `ASCIIEncoding.UTF8`

As an aside, I would suggest using static classes instead of structs. At the moment, someone could write:

```
var x = new KnownParameters.PrettyPrint.Values();
```

... do you *want* that to be legal? (It won't be using a static class.) You might also consider using enums.

Comment: Thanks. This `ASCIIEncoding.UTF8` convinced me to change the name. Now I need to think of a better name for the `ForgeRock.KnownParameters`. I'm not sure yet that `BaseKnownParameters` is adequate. Thanks also for the `struct` versus `static class` argument. Even when the subclasses are `static class` but `KnownParameters` are still `class`, then you can still do `var y = new KnownParameters();`. You're right that this is undesirable, which means I cannot inherit and must find good names.

Comment: @JeroenPluimers-Binck: You can use abstract classes with protected constructors as a starting point... but yes, I'd avoid using inheritance here entirely :)

Comment: I think the current construct was far enough towards the C# edge already (;